# Replace the value by relying on the existing value in XML file

Tags: c#, xml

This is a sample XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">Automation Test</string>
  <string name="current_data_state_incoming_call">Incoming Call</string>
  <string name="current_data_state_outgoing_call">Outgoing Call</string>
  <string name="current_data_state_missed_call">Missed Call</string>
  <string name="current_data_state_photo">Photo</string>
  <string name="current_data_state_video">Video</string>
  <string name="current_data_state_mp3">MP3</string>
  <string name="current_data_state_voice_memo">Voice Memo</string>
  <string name="current_data_state_phone_book">Phone Book</string>
  <string name="current_data_state_phone_booksim">Phone Book(SIM)</string>
  <string name="current_data_state_etc">Etc</string>
  <string name="current_data_state_schedule">S Planner</string>

</resources>
```

I have a large file XML file and I want to replace the values in elements depending on their original value.

For example, I want to replace "Outgoing Call" with another word.
I tried this code:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load("strings.xml");

XmlElement root = xdoc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList elemList = root.GetElementsByTagName("string");

for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{
    xdoc.Save("strings.xml");

    if (elemList[i].InnerText == "Incoming Call")
    {
        // xdoc.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText("strings.xml").Replace(elemList[i].InnerText, "صندوق"));
        //   MessageBox.Show(elemList[i].InnerText);
        elemList[i].SelectSingleNode("resources/string").InnerText="مكالمات قادمة";        
        xdoc.Save("strings.xml");
    }
}
```

and this code

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load("strings.xml");

XmlNodeList aNodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("resources/string");
foreach (XmlNode node in aNodes)
{
    XmlNode child1 = node.SelectSingleNode("string");
    if(child1.InnerText == "Incoming Call")
    {
        child1.InnerText = "اتصالات قادمة";
    }
}
xdoc.Save("strings.xml");
```

I can not replace the value.

===================================
thanx i solve my prob

```
var root2 = new XmlDocument();
        root2.Load("strings.xml");
        var root = new XmlDocument();
        root.Load("strings2.xml");

        foreach (XmlNode e1 in root2.GetElementsByTagName("string"))
        {
            string a = e1.Attributes["name"].Value;
            foreach (XmlNode ee in root.GetElementsByTagName("string"))

            {
                string b = ee.Attributes["name"].Value;
                if (a == b)
                {
                    e1.FirstChild.Value = ee.FirstChild.Value;
                }
            }



        }
        root.Save("strings.xml");
```

Comment: You should post your code as text, not as images. And be aware of formatting.

Comment: i edit it thanx

Comment: Is there any reason you need to use `XmlDocument` instead of LINQ to XML? The latter would make it a *lot* simpler.

Comment: @hamedabdulhadi Thank for following my advice. I've upvoted your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would use LINQ to XML for this. It makes all kinds of things much simpler than `XmlDocument`. Here's a complete example to perform a replacement (loading `input.xml` and writing `output.xml`):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
        ReplaceValue(doc, "Outgoing Call", "Other value");
        doc.Save("output.xml");
    }

    static void ReplaceValue(XDocument doc, string original, string replacement)
    {
        foreach (var element in doc.Descendants("string").Where(x => x.Value == original))
        {
            element.Value = replacement;
        }
    }
}
```

You could easily change the method to throw an exception if it didn't find the value you were trying to replace, or if it found more than one element.

An alternative to replacing by *value* would be to replace by the `name` attribute, which would be a trivial change:

```
static void ReplaceNamedValue(XDocument doc, string name, string replacement)
{
    foreach (var element in doc.Descendants("string")
        .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("name") == name))
    {
        element.Value = replacement;
    }
}
```

You'd then call it like this:

```
ReplaceNamedValue(doc, "current_data_state_outgoing_call", "Other value");
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want to create file on xml on the fly instead of replace.  I prefer using the newer Net library xml linq (XDocument) rather than the older version XmlDocument.  Here is an example of the code I would use :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ident = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><resources></resources>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(ident);

            XElement resources = doc.Root;

            resources.Add(new XElement("string", new object[] {
                new XAttribute("name","app_name"),
                "Automation Test"
            }));

            resources.Add(new XElement("string", new object[] {
                new XAttribute("name","current_data_state_incoming_call"),
                "مكالمات قادمة"
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is code for replacement

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement resource = doc.Root;

            Dictionary<string, XElement> dict = resource.Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            if(dict.ContainsKey("app_name"))
            {
                dict["app_name"].SetValue("Automation Test");
            }

            if (dict.ContainsKey("current_data_state_incoming_call"))
            {
                dict["current_data_state_incoming_call"].SetValue("مكالمات قادمة");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - the question is specifically about "how do I replace elements in an existing file", so an answer that doesn't do that isn't useful IMO.

Comment: yes how do I replace elements in an existing file ?

Comment: The OPs are not experts and sometimes what the OP asks is not the best solution.  In this case it is better to create.  The input xml file is a template and when you get done using replace you end up having the original dummy values in the output file that do not make any sense.

Comment: While I agree that sometimes the original approach isn't the best one, I see no indication that that's the case here. What context do you have to state categorically "In this case it is better to create"? I think you're assuming too much here. Also note that your new example that uses the `name` attribute doesn't replace in the way the OP wanted, which is by *value*.

Comment: Doing with what the OP asks creates a larger xml file than necessary.  Also contains default values that may not be necessary.  Often with xml file when you have a schema there are optional items and most people do not implement all the optional values.

Comment: We have *no idea* whether the file is larger than required. We don't know whether the other values in the file are unnecessary defaults or not - we've just been given an *example*. If you disagree with what the OP is trying to do, I think it would be better to express that in comments rather than in an answer that doesn't answer what's been asked.

Comment: Totally disagree with you.  Replacing values is not very efficient. Replacement algorithm take N * N/2 because you have to search through file to find item to replace.  A straight write takes only N.  Very poor technique to replace.